# Copy Quicksight dataset and analysis to another dataset and datasource

Tags: copy, amazon-quicksight

I have created Analysis in amazon Quicksight using a data source and different datasets within that data source. I have created another Data Source containing same set of tables. But, this data source points to different instance of databse (mysql). Now, I want to copy existing datasets under old data source to new Data source and use the new datasets to create another analysis dashboard. is this possible in amazon ? Please help me how to perform this. If there is some better way, Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

The method I used was to go to the "Save As" option (top right corner) and you can save the copy. The next step is to select the pencil (1 in the image) and after selecting the 3 dots (2 in the image) and select the replace option.

[image]